# Battery float voltage of CN3722

Tags: power-supply, battery-charging, charging, solar-energy, solar-charge-controller

[image]

I want to charge a 2-cell Li-ion battery with CN3722 charging IC. According to my circuit design, the float voltage at the battery terminal should be 8.4V. But, the float voltage is measured as 13.44V when input is of 15V. Also, when I connect the battery,it draws 220mA current for 1 second and after that it goes to 0A. Any idea, why this charging circuit is behaving like this?

[image]

Comment: There's something wrong with your schematic; there's a lot of junction "dots" missing. Can you confirm your circuit actually has these connections?

Comment: Yes, I have checked my schematic. The junctions dots are seems to be missing, but actually the lines are connected. All the components are connected according to the green lines, not as per as dots. Any other query?

Comment: That is really surprisng, because this looks like Eagle, and Eagle really does these dots wherever there's a connection. But I believe you, but that means that the circuit you're looking at is not made as PCB etched from a layout done from this design within Eagle. Got a photo of the PCB as is? Maybe we'll spot a problem. A simple picture of the PCB design might help, too.

Comment: Single layer board file is attached.

Comment: Hm, but that doesn't seem to have the same component numbering as the schematic – not really making this very easy. You don't happen to have the actual schematic used to make this layout?

Comment: OK. You can match now.

Comment: What's the power rating of your R11?

Comment: ah by the way, what kind of battery do you attach, and how charged is it? What's its voltage?

Comment: @MarcusMüller, Rating of R11 is 330mW. I have set my charging current to 1A. So, the power rating of the sense resistor if fine,isn't it? Also, I want to Charge a 2-cell Lithium Ion battery( 7.4V, 2200mAH). That's why,I want battery float voltage as 8.4V. So, as per as data sheet calculation, I choose R8=300K and R9=120K.

Comment: Anyone, please give me some suggestions.

Comment: Please give me some suggestion.

Comment: In my circuit I have use SI4401 P channel MOSFET, whose VDSS = 40V. I have search in internet and found that in all schematic, they are using a MOSFET whose VDSS=30V. So, is there any possibility that could be a reason for the above problem?